# android layoutbackgroundimage strech

Tags: android

in my application i set image on background of screen but is strech its pixel like this screen

[image]

i see a solution use  bitmapstrech.xml   put onbackground but now screen look like this

[image]

after use bitmapSrech.xml on background  how do i adjust my background to stop streching image???

```
               <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bitmapstrech"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/back" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/options1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why don't you put a third `ImageView` (between the two existing ones) and set its background resource from that image. Two benefits here: 1 . It will not be stretched. 2. it will occupy just the needed space and will not interfere with the two buttons (from left and right).

Comment: how?? how any idea????

Comment: Paste the image file into the drawables folder (where you keep the other image resources). Put `<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logoImage" >` between the two `ImageViews` you got there.

Comment: @NightCrawler - they are working, but the images are too small :)

Comment: is there any method to prevent background form streching?

Comment: yeah, you set it programmatically and according to its holder (by scaling it).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/back" >
    </ImageView>

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bitmap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bitmapstrech" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/test_button_image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/options1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: so u mean customize background with imageview not add image as background on Relativelayout??

Answer (score 0):

you can use 9 patch image from your android sdk tool.
android-sdk\tools\draw9patch.bat
for more information check this link:
http://www.androiddom.com/2011/05/android-9-patch-image-tutorial.html
http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html